# Magento 1.9.0.1 removing cash/credit card base payment

Tags: magento

Is it possible to removed CreditCard/Cash base payment 

and **use points base**  to purchase product to my magento store???

 Ex: if i have 10points on my magento user account
i can buy product which is below 10price :)

im a newbie in this and don't have someone to talk to....
hehehe thanks for understanding my newbie like question hahaha

right now im trying

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module

is it what im looking for?
thanks if someone direct me to the right path hehehehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know magento is not created for that, if you really need to do something like that in magento , you probably need to dig up its code and change function of  things nabout payment